# How to send an email when google sheet cell is blank for two columns only?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make the script send me an email whenever a cell is blank in columns "U" and "V" automatically using a trigger.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // Start at second row because the first row contains the data labels
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()

  // Fetch the range of cells, in this case A2:T
  // Column B, row[2] = Email Address, Column C, row[1] = Name
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow, lastCol)

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
   var emailAddress = 'email@address.com'; // 
    var message = "Hi " + row[2] + ",\n Could you please fill out the form:" + "\n 'insert website here'" + "\n Thank you"; // Assemble the body text
        var cell = row[19]; // Last column
    if (cell == " ") { 
   var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
}
```

I got the code to work once but for some reason it suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to sent an email by running the script when the Google form is submitted.

  - In this case, you want to check the edited row.
  - Although in your script, `" "` which is one space is used as the blank, I thought that the blank you think might be `""`.
- You want to automatically run the script using the OnSubmit event trigger.

From your replying, I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, when the cell of column "T" is the blank, the script in the if statement is run.
- The row which is not edited is checked. So when the cells of column "U" and "V" of several rows are the blank, the email is sent every row.

Flow:

The flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. When the values are submitted from the Google Form, the installed OnSubmit event trigger is fired.

   - By this, the function of `sample` is run.
2. When both values of the column "U" and the column "V" at the row that the values is put are the blank, the script in the if statement is run.

   - By this, `MailApp.sendEmail()` is run.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this, [please install the OnSubmit event trigger to the function of `sample` as the installable trigger.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) And please set the email address to `var emailAddress = 'email@address.com';`.

```
function sample(e) {
  var blank = "";
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var editRow = range.getRow();
  var row = sheet.getRange(editRow, 1, 1, 22).getValues()[0];
  if (row.splice(-2).every(function(e) {return e == blank})) {
    var emailAddress = 'email@address.com';
    var message = "Hi " + row[2] + ",\n Could you please fill out the form:" + "\n 'insert website here'" + "\n Thank you";
    var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to use one space like `" "` as the blank, please modify `var blank = "";` to `var blank = " ";`.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

### Added:

- You want to use the specific sheet in the Spreadsheet as the target sheet.

  - The sheet name of the specific sheet is `PIC`.

I could understand about your additional question. For achieving this, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function sample(e) {
  var blank = "";
  var range = e.range;

  // var sheet = range.getSheet(); // removed
  var sheetName = "PIC"; // Added
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetName); // Added

  var editRow = range.getRow();
  var row = sheet.getRange(editRow, 1, 1, 22).getValues()[0];
  if (row.splice(-2).every(function(e) {return e == blank})) {
    var emailAddress = 'email@address.com';
    var message = "Hi " + row[2] + ",\n Could you please fill out the form:" + "\n 'insert website here'" + "\n Thank you";
    var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 3, file "Copy of PLI")" and i dont know why

Comment: @Alvis Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your question, the function of `sample` is run by the installable OnEdit event trigger. From your replying, I thought that you might directly run the function by the script editor. If it's so, please manually edit the Spreadsheet. By this, the function is automatically run. And when the values of cells of column "U" and "V" are removed, the script of if statement is run and the email is sent.

Comment: Thanks but the spreadsheet is for a google form response so will it send an email to notify me when there is a blank cell after someone submits a response?

Comment: @Alvis Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. I couldn't notice that you want to run the OnSubmit event trigger from your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. In this case, the OnEdit event trigger cannot be used. So it is required to modify the script. So could you please give me a time to modify it? I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Alvis I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? In that case, please install the OnSubmit event trigger to the function of `sample`. By this, when the Google form is submitted, the script is run. And when the values of column "U" and "V" are blank, `MailApp.sendEmail()` is run. In this script, `""` is used as the blank. If in your situation, `" "` which is one space is used as the blank, please modify `var blank = "";` to `var blank = " ";`. If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize, again.

Comment: I dont know why you keep apologizing because you h'v been a great help. Thanks!

Comment: @Alvis Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I misunderstood OnEdit event trigger and OnSubmit event trigger. I couldn't consider both situations. But I could study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: one more question since its spamming me emails now. How do i set it to only 1 sheet? my sheet is called "PIC" i did this var sheetName = "PIC"; var sheet = range.SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

Comment: @Alvis About your additional question, I added the modified script. Could you please confirm it?